# parse RGB values from a string with php

Tags: php, parsing, rgb

Is there a way to parse multiple RGB values from a string? In what way should the colours be coded?

Eg.

`$string = "foobar [rgb:123abc] some other text and another color: [rgb:ffeecc]"`

I want `[rgb:xxxxxx]` to be replaced with something like `<div style="background: #xxxxxx;">&nbsp;</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this regex to pick up the pattern...

```
/\[rgb:([0-9a-f]{6})\]/i
```